# Webdriver.io - can not get firefox to run

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to get firefox to run in webdriver.io 5. This is on a Linux cloud.

I get:

```
2020-02-28T02:32:33.472Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2020-02-28T02:32:33.475Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.818Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] RUNNING in firefox - /build/main.js
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.881Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the webdriver protocol
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.883Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/session
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.883Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'firefox', 'moz:firefoxOptions': [Object] },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'firefox', 'moz:firefoxOptions': { args: [Array] } }
}
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.899Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.899Z INFO webdriver: Retrying 1/3
```

Here is my config:

````
exports.config = {
    runner: 'local',
    path: '/',
    specs: [
        './build/**/*.js'
    ],
    maxInstances: 10,
    capabilities: [
      {   
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "moz:firefoxOptions": {
            "args": ["-headless"],
          }
      }
    ],
    logLevel: 'info',
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    reporters: ['spec'],
    framework: 'mocha',
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
    services: [
    ],
}```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
````

Comment: are you using selenium server or how you are triggering gecko driver?

Comment: Do I need selenium if I use Firefox headless?

Comment: its a choice you can make. Please refer to the boilerplates available.

Answer (score 1):

The `path` should be set to `path: "/wd/hub"` and your services seems to be empty. You can use webdriverio with mocha in two different ways. With selenium or without.

Please refer to boiler plates from official docs [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/boilerplate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-0] 2020-02-28T02:32:33.899Z WARN webdriver: Request failed due to connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

If you are using selenium-standalone, please make sure that you have both the java jdk & sdk installed on your machine. let me know if this worked for you.